# How to handle a column having the number of children with some values being represented with some dummy value?

Tags: categorical-data, dataset, missing-data, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset which has a column representing the number of children. The values vary from 0 to 6. But the issue is that there are many entries which have values like 84, 94, 97, 98 and 99, which obviously cannot be the number of children. And I do not know what these numbers represent. I am struggling, because I don't know what do with these numbers, and the main trouble is that, these extream values are there in the majority of rows (around 90% times).

Should I delete this column? Or is there any way to manage this particular scenario?

Comment: If 90% of your values are essentially impossible, then there is not much information in the column. I would either find out more about the dataset to see if anything can be salvaged, or exclude it from analysis.

Comment: @mkt: I can not get more details on the data set. So it will be better to delete the column itself. Thank you mkt.

Comment: @mkt:  I am new to data science, I just want to know one more thing, does it make sense to divide this column by considering 0 to 6 as the first category and 84 to 99 as the second category?

Comment: Hard to say what the best choice is without more information. You could drop the column. You could try ignoring the problem as long as you are careful about cross-validation to get your error estimates. You could also create an extra categorical variable that distinguishes between believable/unbelievable values. Fundamentally, the problem is that you do not know what the numbers in that column mean - and that would worry me.

Comment: Yes. what you told is correct. I will try this three possibilities and see which one is the best. Thanks again @mkt...

Comment: I'd be afraid. Very afraid. If there is one column that seems to obviously not be what it is labeled, then what about other columns?  If you can't get information on this data set, I might just stop all my analysis of it. Not just this column, but the whole thing. 

It is, in general, dangerous to do analysis on a data set you don't fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you are collecting data you often end up in a situation where you need to include additional codes for special situations: e.g. you did not ask the number of children if the respondent was younger than 15. Very common is a code for refused to answer and does not know. Your values 99 98 are pretty traditional codes for such special situations.

However this needs to be in the documentation that came with the data. Once you have found what those codes mean you can make an informed decision. If you don't have the documentation then you cannot use the entire dataset (not just this one column). You need to understand what the values mean, otherwise any result will automatically become meaningless (GIGO).

Comment: I guess it makes sense to drop the analysis as such, as I am not able to find more information regarding the dataset. And thanks for the answer.

Comment: My answer was intended to encourage you to find the documentation, not for you to just give up. If this is serious data, then that documentation exists.

Comment: I completely understood that :). I was trying out a dataset that I found online for myself. I have tried to check with the providers for more details. But not much I could extract from there.